# Change keyboard layout occurs a black line

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm moving up the view when the keyboard appears.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

But when changing the language by clicking up globe icon at the bottom of the keyboard and when the language is not English it appears a black line.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this black lilne while showing suggestions for English and not for other languages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that the keyboard is actually changing its frame when you switch to another layout.

Register to `UIResponder.keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` and update your frame accordingly.

More info on this notification are available here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621619-keyboarddidchangeframenotificati